# AWS CloudFront Cors

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, amazon-cloudfront

Trying to use CloudFront but getting the following CORs error (CORs Access-Control-Allow-Origin):

```
Access to Font at 'https://d1nic7y05p6u7o.cloudfront.net/pub/static/version1512716215/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/fonts/opensans/semibold/opensans-600.ttf' from origin 'https://website.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://website.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I'm not using an S3 bucket so I can't just set CORs there (goes to the website to get the media). I whitelisted "Origin" but not sure how to forward that request to s3 or something to do the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"? A website said I needed to set the header on my apache server, didn't make sense to me but I tried it and still didn't work.

Comment: The error message indicates that you have already configured *something* to add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header, but it is being added incorrectly -- there is a trailing slash that should not be there.  You will need to figure out what, on your web server, is adding this incorrectly.  CloudFront wouldn't be adding it on its own.

Comment: I accidentally added the trailing slash when replacing the urls. Isn't this error normal CORs functionality? Request sent from one server to different server. If I had control of cloudfront server I'd add {Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"} to .htaccess and the error would go away.

Comment: Go back and create at the error again, and examine it very carefully.  In its current form, it's nonsensical, because it is claiming that since the header allows only `https://website.com` it therefore disallows `https://website.com` which is self-contradictory.  I believe you may have made another transcription error.

Comment: I apologize, updated. Positive this is correct. Somehow I need to add header on cloudfront.

Answer (score 0):

On the server I had to add

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

In AWS allow OPTIONS header and add Access-Control-Allow-Origin (Header Name) and * (Value) to Origin Custom Headers.

Important to note some reason I had to create a new distribution in order for it to work.